# nginx routes to wrong domain (most of the time)

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have an nginx set up with four domains, including phpMyAdmin; and everything has been working finde until lately. Actually, I found out today, while I was running the updates on the machine (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS). Now, while the other domains work perfectly, trying to access phpMyAdmin routes to my third domain.

I even have an open tab with the phpmyadmin working; but every time I try to open it in a new tab, it´s routed to the third domain.
That is ... a refresh did change nothing: I still got the phpMyAdmin login screen; but trying to log in took me to domain 3; and going back resulted in a 403 - Forbidden.

the phpmyadmin config (from nginx/sites-enabled):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root    /var/www/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name ~^(\w+\.)?phpmyadmin\.test$;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }
}
```

`server_name` originally was `~^((.*)\.)?phpmyadmin\.test`, but I changed it to match the other domains. That did not change the irritating behaviour.

I am, mildly said, wildly confused. Any ideas?